# Symfony2 exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Parameter for route must match "[^/]++" to generate a corresponding URL.")

Tags: php, symfony

I keep getting following error when use back slash in object name and want to proceed through object URL:

*An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Parameter "name" for route "object_show" must match "[^/]++" ("black/white" given) to generate a corresponding URL.") in /ObjectBundle/Resources/views/Object/index.html.twig*

**Controller**

```
/**
 * @Route("/show/{user}/{name}", name="object_show")
 * @Template()
 */
public function showAction($user, $name, Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('UserBundle:User')
                 ->findBy(['username'=> $user]);
    $object = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ObjectBundle:Object')
                   ->findOneBy(['name' => $name, 'user' => $user]);

    return array('object' => $object);
}
```

How can I allow use of back slash for object name and be able to generate corresponding URL?

**Template**

```
      {% for object in objects %}
        <div class="item" id="object_{{ object.id }}">
            <a href="{{ path('object_show',
                     {'user': object.user.username, 'name' : object.name }) }}">
                <div class="title">{{ object.name }}</div>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: May we see your template?

Comment: @scoolnico sure, I added code to my question

Comment: First, in your controller you have to return `objects` due to the loop in your twig: `return array('objects'  => $object);` ... And your loop is not necessary because you only fetch 1 result in your query with the native `findOneBy` method...

Comment: @scoolnico 'objects' is the result of different action, the problem is in href of the link. If the name doesn't contain slash, everything works fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `, requirements={"name"=".+"}` part into your route definition. For example:

```
/**
 * @Route("/show/{user}/{name}", name="object_show", requirements={"name"=".+"})
 * @Template()
 */
public function showAction($user, $name, Request $request)
```

See the manual section: [manual](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html).

Answer (score 2):

Routes are matched with regular expressions.

`"[^/]++"` is the default pattern that variable values need to match. It will match everything that's not a `/`. You're getting an exception, since the value you're passing as `name` is `black/white` (so it contains a `/` which is not allowed).

If the value is not correct - clean it.

If the value is correct and you actually need to match it, you can change the requirements for the name parameter. For example:

```php
/**
 * @Route(
 *     "/show/{user}/{name}",
 *     name="object_show",
 *     requirements={"name": ".+"}
 * )
 */
```

It'll accept any characters, so be careful if that's what you really want. You'll need to adapt the requirements for your needs.

Related routing docs can be found here:

- [Adding requirements](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#adding-requirements)
- [Slash in parameters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html)